# Wanted: Most elegant way to code an anonymous class for mocking

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

I'm mocking part of the Net::SFTP for my tests. The following mimicks `dir.entries`, `entry.name` and `entry.attributes.size` by reading locally from `fixture_path`:

```
class MockedSFTP
  mattr_accessor :fixture_path
  def dir
    Class.new do
      def entries(path)
        MockedSFTP.fixture_path.join(path.sub(%r{^/}, '')).children.map do |child|
          OpenStruct.new(
            name: child.basename,
            attributes: OpenStruct.new(size: child.size)
          )
        end
      end
    end.new
  end
end
```

An alternative would be:

```
class MockedSFTP
  mattr_accessor :fixture_path
  def dir
    object = Object.new
    def object.entries(path)
      MockedSFTP.fixture_path.join(path.sub(%r{^/}, '')).children.map do |child|
        OpenStruct.new(
          name: child.basename,
          attributes: OpenStruct.new(size: child.size)
        )
      end
    end
    object
  end
end
```

Both versions work absolutely fine, however, I don't like neither of them. The `Class.new do ... end.new` is just ugly and I'm no fan of `object = Object.new; ...; object` code at all.

Is there a third way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

How about actually declaring the class?

```
class MockedSFTP

  mattr_accessor :fixture_path

  class Dir
    def entries(path)
      MockedSFTP.fixture_path.join(path.sub(%r{^/}, '')).children.map do |child|
        OpenStruct.new(
          name: child.basename,
          attributes: OpenStruct.new(size: child.size)
        )
      end
    end
  end

  def dir
    Dir.new
  end
end
```

Comment: That was my first shot, but it's even more verbose. I was looking for a more "anonymous" approach.